# EDSDK Press Shutter Button remotely

Tags: c#, edsdk, canon-sdk

I'm trying to remote control my Canon EOS 1000D with Canon's EDSDK 3.6.1 in C#.

I'm calling

```
uint CameraCommand_PressShutterButton  = 0x00000004;
uint CameraCommand_ShutterButton_Completely = 0x00000003;

int error = EdsSendCommand(camRef, CameraCommand_PressShutterButton, CameraCommand_ShutterButton_Completely);
```

However, `EdsSendCommand` always returns `0x00000060` what means "invalid parameter".

Any ideas, what went wrong here? 3 is the parameter I found on [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp). I tried `CameraCommand_ShutterButton_Completely_NonAF = 0x00010003` as well with the same result.

Or is there another way to remote shutter this camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1000D is quite old already and it is most likely that it does not support the shutter button command. This command is (to my knowledge) the only one (besides video) that is only supported by newer cameras.

If you just want to take a picture, you can use the `TakePicture` command (ID is 0, parameter also 0).

Comment: Do you know another way to remote shutter a 1000D? Probably another command I should use?

Comment: @Spock,  if you just want to take a picture, you can use the TakePicture command (ID is 0, parameter also 0). but this command can't do anything else but taking a photo. other than that you can only use a newer camera

Comment: Thanks @Johannes! `TakePicture` is all I need... :-)

Comment: no problem! note that with TakePicture you can't control if the autofocus should be used or not. If the lens has AF on, it will be used.

Comment: I know, but that's no problem for me. Thanks! I think, for my scenario (a photo booth) a generally disabled AF will do.